# For loop within a function in Mathematica

Tags: for-loop, wolfram-mathematica

I have the following piece of code which I wrote in python.

```
def func(r,f):
    for k in np.arange(Nb-1):
    temp = 0
    temp += f[r][k]*f[r][k+1]*np.sqrt(k+1)
    return temp
```

How do I do the same in Mathematica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
func[r_,f_]:=Sum[f[[r,k]] f[[r,k+1]] Sqrt[k+1] , {k,Nb-1}]
```

If you really want a For loop :

```
  func[r_,f_]:=(temp=0;For[ ...,temp+= .. ] ; temp)
```

You can RTFM the For[] syntax, I dont think I've ever used it but it looks like "c"

Comment: The `Sum` command is a obvious one, I was just looking for a way to include procedural functional programming in mathematica, the `()` thing works for it, Thanks.